# How to integrate $\frac{dc}{dt} = A-Bc $

Tags: integration

At 1:50 of this video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xhuvQvXDVm8

$$\frac{\mathrm dc}{\mathrm dt} = A-Bc $$

The next step is that you must "realize that you have the same variable here as below it", and somehow get:

$$-\frac{1}{B} \frac{\mathrm d(A-Bc)}{(A-Bc)} = \mathrm dt$$

What were the **exact steps** performed to get from the previous line to this one?

Multiply both sides by $\mathrm dt$.
Divide both sides by $(A-Bc)$? 
Then..?

I am completely lost. Maybe it is a well-known thing, but googling for this formula hasn't helped.

The integration is then performed to get

$$\ln(A-Bc) = -Bt + IC$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, notice $\frac{\mathrm{d}(A-Bc)}{\mathrm{d}c} = -B$.  Then multiply your starting equation through by $\frac{\mathrm{d}(A-Bc)}{\mathrm{d}c}$ and manipulate, using the chain rule and algebra:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}(A-Bc)}{\mathrm{d}c} \frac{\mathrm{d}c}{\mathrm{d}t} &= \frac{\mathrm{d}(A-Bc)}{\mathrm{d}c} (A-Bc)  \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}(A-Bc)}{\mathrm{d}t} &= -B (A-Bc)  \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}(A-Bc)}{-B (A-Bc)} &= \mathrm{d}t  \\
\frac{-1}{B} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}(A-Bc)}{(A-Bc)} &= \mathrm{d}t  \text{.}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

This helps you to directly integrate.

$-\frac{1}{B}$ $\frac{d(A-Bc)}{(A-Bc)}$ = $\frac{dc}{(A-Bc)}$

You could also use u-substitution instead of this trick.